# line bundle descents?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let the permutation group $S_4$ act on $\mathbb C^4$ by permuting the coordinates. Consider the categorical quotient $\mathbb P(\mathbb C^4)/S_4$. It is a projective variety by a theorem of Mumford. Does the line bundle $\mathcal O(1)^{\otimes 12}$ on $\mathbb P(\mathbb C^4)$ descents to the quotient $\mathbb P(\mathbb C^4)/S_4$ ?